# Why would you avoid C++ keywords in Java?

Tags: java, c++, keyword

A popular editor uses highlighting to help programmers avoid using C++ keywords in Java. The following words are displayed using the same colors as a syntax error:

```
auto delete extern friend inline redeclared register signed sizeof
struct template typedef union unsigned operator
```

Why would this be considered important?

Comment: My silly guess is they want to ease porting when you decide to drop java and start with C++.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is to prevent people just glancing at the code from mistaking what language it's written in... but that seems flimsy at best. I've never heard of avoiding C++ keywords in Java before.

Comment: I think it makes your code harder to understand.  Many developers work in more than just Java and would have certain assumptions or expectations around the purpose and functionality that those keywords imply.

Comment: How did `redeclared` sneak in there?

Comment: My silly guess is the opposite of Johannes': to help C++ programmers from trying to use constructs that don't apply in Java when they use that editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid confusion.  The largest migration path in the entire industry over the last 15 years was from C++ to Java.  Thus, it would be wise to avoid using those words in a new context where they no longer mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the editor developers were lazy and used a common set of reserved keywords across languages?